# Cannot access session in Magento2

Tags: magento2, session

I'm not able to access customer session in my block. Session does not return customer. Here is my code:

```
<?php
namespace YS\India\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Header
extends Template
{
protected $session;
protected $customerRepository;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $session,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->session = $session;

    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getBaseUrl(){
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
}

public function isCustomerLogged(){
    return $this->session->isLoggedIn();
}

public function getLoggedCustomerName(){

    return $this->session->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
}
}
```

Then I created a test controller:

```
<?php

namespace YS\India\Controller\Auth;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;

class Test extends AbstractAccount
{ 
protected $session;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession
)
{
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    echo $this->session->isLoggedIn() ? "yes" : "no";

    echo "<br/>" . $this->session->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
}
}
```

This controller works fine and gives the first name.

Please help what is I'm missing in block

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cacheable=false in layout file did the trick.

<block class="YS\India\Block\Header" template="header/top_header.phtml" **cacheable="false"**>

Comment: The reason behind this is, that cacheable blocks are "Depersonalized" to avoid that customer data are stored in the Magento cache and presented to other customers. The solution you mentioned is correct, but you have to recognize, that the page cache will not work anymore for that particular page.

Comment: Using `cacheable=false` nowadays is a bad practice and it should not be recommended. Instead, any block should be made Full Page Cache compatible (`cacheable=true`). If you want to use customer-specific details anyway, use the procedure of Private Content to do so: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cache/cache-priv-priv.html

Answer (score -1):

If you can't access session by instance of `Magento\Customer\Model\Session`
Try instance `Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` 

Sample:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
){
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
}

public function getCustomerSession()
{
    $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)->getSession();
}
```

Comment: Hi mrtuvn, getValue(..) returns boolean value.

Comment: You can use the http context to get the information if the customer is logged in or not. You cannot get detailed customer information that way. Please do not try to load the customer object in your objects by using the customer_id in the session.